# On the proof of a corollary of Cauchy's Residue theorem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

A corollary of Cauchy's residue theorem states that for any function $f$ that is holomorphic on an open subset $\mathbb{D}\in\mathbb{C}$ integrated over a closed path $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{D}$, the result yields:
$$\oint_{\Gamma}f(z)\ dz=0$$
This is a beautiful property but I'm having trouble getting a grasp of it intuitively speaking. I've attempted it to try and prove it in my own way but I have no idea as to whether it's even going down the right track:

Let $\Gamma$ be a closed path in the same conditions as described, and let $\phi(t)$ be a parametrisation of that curve, $t\in(a,b)$. This means we can re-write the integrals as:
$$\oint_{\Gamma}f(z)\ dz=\int_a^bf(\phi(t))\phi'(t)\ dt$$
Now, essentially, I'm inclined to say that since it is a closed loop then it is tempting to say that $a$ and $b$ represent the same end point on our curve, and that this is analgous to saying that:
$$\int_a^af(x)\ dx=0$$
But that's obviously not rigorous at all. I've also tried to implement the Cauchy Riemann equations into this, although nothing has come of it.

If anybody has a nice succinct way of at least effectively conveying the big idea of what is going on here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does $\Bbb D$ denote the unit disk or an arbitrary domain in $\Bbb C$? The “corollary” as you state it holds only if the domain is *simply connected,* that is [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem). As stated in the Wikipedia article, it is a consequence of Green's theorem if one assume that the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous.

Comment: the result is not generally true if $f$ is not analytic while it makes sense to talk about the integral of $f$ for any continuous or even just integrable $f$; C-R appear as by using Green's theorem the line integral becomes the domain integral of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}d\bar z \wedge dz$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$ written in $(x,y)$ coordinates are exactly the C-R equations